# Calling attribute from factory in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am actually having problems to retrieve data from my factory.

```
.factory('Spooler', ['$http', '$q', '$log', 'Domains', function ($http, $q, $log, Domains) {

var Spooler = function (id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = null;
};

Spooler.prototype.load = function () {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/spooler/' + this.id + '/load')
        .success(function(data) {
            self.name = data.name;
            deferred.resolve(self);
        })
        .error(function(err, code) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        $log.error(err, code);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

This sets the factory so I can call : `var spooler = new Spooler(1)`, which returns the spooler (i can read the good name i nthe controller logs). My question is: how can I have access to the name attribute ? I did another method in the factory :

```
Spooler.prototype.getName =  function() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Why can't I just call `spooler.name` ? since the spooler returns the name in the `controller` ?

Comment: Your factory more looks like service.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your spooler can't just use the .name property is because your property is actually `null` until your promise is resolved. If you need to be able to reliably access the name and other properties, either use the .then function on your load or provide the callback.

```
var myspooler = Spooler(1);

myspooler.load().then(function(data){
   ... do something with your data ...
});
```

or

```
myspooler.load(function(data){
  ... do something with your data ...
})
```

and your service becomes

```
Spooler.prototype.load = function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    var post = $http.post('/spooler/' + this.id + '/load')
        .success(function(data) {
            self.name = data.name;
            callback(data);
        })
        .error(function(err, code) {
           callback(err);
        $log.error(err, code);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Does that mean that i should use then() after calling spooler.load() ?

Comment: added how to implement.